# Re-merge a branch into Master

Tags: git, github, merge, bitbucket, branch

I created and pushed a branch called Branch-A. Someone merged Branch-A into Branch-B, deleted the changes I added to Branch-A and merged Branch-B into Master. I want to merge my changes in Branch-A into master. When I try to create a pull request, I don't see my changes in the difference. What is the best way to merge my changes in Branch-A to Master?

Comment: When you say "Someone...deleted the changes I added", do you mean they *reverted* your changes using `git revert`? If yes, you could revert the revert(s), or you'll need to change the IDs of your commits so you can bring them in again. (e.g. cherry-pick or rebase)

Comment: @TTT Thanks for the comment. They didn't revert the commit. They manually reverted the changes by updating the files. Then they created a commit along with other changes to Branch B. The problem with cherry picking is, I have a bunch of commits in Branch A.

Comment: It's not critical *how* they un-did your work. What matters is that as far as Git is concerned, your work is already *in*. Whoever undid it (let's call him Bob) has told Git: "Take Pranav's work. Now improve it by adding my work." Git has done all of that, and your work is done. The fact that Bob undid it (and not *how* he undid it) means that you have to do your work over again. Cherry-picking will make that easier, but not necessarily easy. That's not Git's fault, that's Bob's.

Comment: @torek I understand. Cherry-picking will make the work easier than redoing it.

Comment: Note you can cherry-pick a range of commits too: `git cherry-pick parent-of-first-commit-ID..last-commit-ID`. Or, you could squash all of your commits into a single commit (or just a few if you prefer), and then cherry-pick that smaller number of commits.

Comment: @TTT Squashing and cherry-picking is what I was looking for. Thank you!